How to fix this broken irrigation pipe system?
I have an irrigation system in my house with a broken pipe. The controllable valve has a screw connector which attaches to a short pipe which connects to a splitter which diverts water to different parts of the garden. See attached image.
This short pipe has cracked and broken off (red circle) but I’m unable to detach any of the pipes (blue circles) from the splitter. They don't unscrew or have any obvious connectors. All the pipes spin in the housing but have no movement in/out to suggest I can disconnect them.
How do I disconnect these pipes from one another? Do I cut them apart and replace bits of the system?


You have two types of connections.
The red and the blue above it are screw on compression type
The others are just push in type.
For the screw type unscrew and pull out.
For the others, if you apply enough force you can pull them out.
